# I can't type letter b in browser input quill-editor

Tags: cordova, quill, ngx-quill

I can't type letter b in my browser app using quill-editor

```
<quill-editor trackChanges="all" [modules]="modules" (onEditorCreated)="addBindingCreated($event)"
            [styles]="{height: '200px'}" [(ngModel)]="note" placeholder="Inserer text ici"></quill-editor>
```